# want to display flash object in smooth box?

Tags: flash, smoothing

I want to display flash content in smooth box.

Right now it totally disables tags for flash content, no code at that place instead of flash object code.

Comment: I deleted my answer, the objectHide function is not part of the script's core. Sorry.

Comment: I can't find anything in the script that would point to Flash not working. Can you describe what happens when you try to embed a flash movie? Can you try adding a sourrounding container to the movie? Can you post an on-line example to look at?

Comment: Hi Pekka,
thanx for your reply.
I have got the solution.
This question is closed.
Keep in Touch

Comment: @Rajendra I hope you will **post your solution as your answer** (and **accept** it as the answer) so we can all see! Thanks.